# SSO between MVCForum and Umbraco7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, forms-authentication, umbraco7

I need to integrate SSO between `MVCForum` (forum of my company) and `Umbraco7` (manages CMS for my company).

However I am struggling to get the `shared authentication` to work. I tried several ways which were suggested on some other threads but it is still not running as expected.

Here is what I did:

**1. In MVCForum (forum.mywebsite.com)**

1.1. Machine key in web.xml:

```
<machineKey validationKey="the same key with Umbraco7" decryptionKey="the same key with Umbraco7" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

1.2. Authenticate forms in web.xml

```
<forms name="MY-SSO-AUTH" protection="All" path="/" timeout="43200" domain="forum.mywebsite.com" loginUrl="/Members/LogOn" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
```

**2. In Umbraco7 (news.mywebsite.com)**

2.1. Machine key in web.xml:

```
<machineKey validationKey="the same key with MVCForum" decryptionKey="the same key with MVCForum" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

2.2. Authenticate forms in web.xml

```
<forms name="MY-SSO-AUTH" protection="All" path="/" timeout="43200" domain="mywebsite.com" loginUrl="/Members/LogOn" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
```

**3. Database**

I created a separate DB for each but both of them have the same list of users (with the same value of some main properties such as same username, email, address, passowrd, roles, etc). So I think the issue doesn't come from here.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant (SSO = single sign on).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing domain attribute in **both** configuration files to: **mywebsite.com**
Currently you have *domain="forum.mywebsite.com"* in MVCForum configuration.
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/2112891)